# Copy/Paste Chart in Range without SELECT

Tags: excel, vba

I have a bar chart that shows data for each row. I plan to have 1 chart for each row in column `L`. **Macro recorder** gives me long  and inefficient code, which I would like to  combine in one line (marked as comment), which unfortunately does not work. I would also like to avoid, if possible, any cycles e.g. `For`.

```
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 4").Activate
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
    Range("L7").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("L8").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    'ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 4").Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("L7:L8")

'Later I have a code to adapt each graph to the row it is in
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code if you dont want to use select statement...

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.ChartArea.Copy
```

Or this one;

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.Parent.Copy
ActiveSheet.Paste ActiveSheet.Range("L7")
```